# Gradle tasks organization

Tags: gradle

I have a problem in organizing my build in manageable way. In my gradle build there are large number of tasks since for each specific work element,  gradle require a task of that type. For ex: to copy a file gradle needs Copy task type, and to zip a file gradle needs Zip task type, to delete few files gradle needs Delete task type. Javadoc , Jar , Ear etc also require their task types. Eventually build has large number of tasks and to run all these in specific order I have to use

```
taskA.mustRunAfter taskB
```

Applying these rules to for all the tasks make build more unmanageable. Is there a way to program all those work elements ( i.e, copy files, zip files, create a jar and javadoc, etc ) in one task ( like provided in ant )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't using `dependsOn`? You'll need to specify a *lot* more `mustRunAfter` statements to achieve the same ordering that `dependsOn` can get you. At least, that's my experience. Only use `mustRunAfter` when you have an ordering issue that explicitly is *not* a dependency.

For example, we use gradle to install and uninstall testing environments. If both are run than `install.mustRunAfter uninstall` (to do a refresh) but clearly install doesn't always actually *depend* on uninstall so we use `mustRunAfter`.

That said, one way you can run many elements in one task is to use a series of ant goals.

```
task lotsOfStuffAtOnce {
    ext.paulaProp = 'brillant'
} << {
    ant.copy ...
    ant.zip ...
    ant.jar ...
}
```

I still think that overall the preferred philosophy is to use tasks with a proper mix of `dependsOn` and `mustRunAfter`, but different situations call for different results so who am I to judge? If you're looking to accomplish several steps all as one unit of work (one task) the above code is the cleanest way I can think of doing it.

If you don't have experience calling ant from gradle, [the user docs](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html) will show you that it's a pretty mechanical transformation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. Calling ant task will work, but `dependsOn` does not give exact order [GRADLE-427](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-427).

Comment: The ordering from dependsOn will respect exactly what you tell it, but there are certainly scenarios that require some liberal uses of mustRunAfter. A little trial and error will sort it out, I'm sure!